# If I get a ticket for fishing without license, will buying a licence make my ticket go away?

Tags: united-states, fishing, legality

I live in Oklahoma where a relative and I were fishing.

We are new to fishing and didn't know you needed a license. We got stopped and the game warden gave us two options: buy a temp license or get a ticket. 
We didn't have the $90 bucks so we got the ticket.

Then he said if we come back later that week and give him $50 for a temp license he will drop the ticket and we won't have to go to court.

We later got our license  from a store and when we contacted him he said it doesn't matter: we either get the temp license *from him* or the ticket will process through the court.

He also said that the difference is that we didn't have the license beforehand. So we still got the citation but we're not sure how buying a temp license from him isn't the same?

Should we fight this in court?

Comment: 1 - Save any recordings or emails you've received.
2 - Call your state Department of Natural Resources with such.
3 - Go to court.

Any officer demanding you pay them directly is very suspicious.

Comment: My first thought was "sounds like a bribe", but it appears this may be legit per https://www.ok.gov/odc/documents/SB1278_int.rtf in which case a strict reading would suggest that buying a license from the store wouldn't matter, as it wouldn't have been in effect at the time of the offense.

Comment: It does look suspicious, but it could also be that he can arrange for the license to be valid for the moment you got the ticket.

Comment: all the above......

Comment: His insisting after you got a license from the store is strange indeed. However usually you cannot buy a license afterwards for obvious reasons: Who would buy one before when you could just try not being caught with no consequences. So I guess the offer to get a license afterwards from him was a goodwill offer, as he believed you that you really did not know. In that case it is clear that it only goes through him and not anybody else.

Comment: But isn't that kind of going against the law? If buy a license after the fact won't matter then it shouldn't if we got it from him or not. Also the citations are already in the system as we have a court data I thought only the judge can throw it oit

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this entails legal issues and is not within the scope of this site.

Comment: It sounds a bit as if the warden is asking for a bribe.

Answer (score 7):

He's on the take.  Contact the main office, explain the whole thing.  They may wish your help to nab him.

---

In general I don't know *any* jurisdiction where getting the permit after getting caught absolves you of the penalty.  If this were the case, then no one would buy the permit first.

Comment: I assume that it is usual procedure where he lives to get the $50 temporary license beforehand (for that price). So it seems quite fine to me; I'd go with the interpretation that the officer was indeed believing that they trespassed unintentionally and were truly sorry, instead of trying to avoid paying the license. As long as the $50 license they get afterwards is an official act and not disappearing in the wallet of the officer, obviously.   -- The issue with buying one in the shop complicates things and will, sadly, probably lead to the officer not being that friendly in the future.

Comment: The whole "buy from me" does look a bit fishy. (see what I've done there :D) Anyway. The wander could be holding your ticket and getting a temp license from him would mean he could void it somehow. I'd say if he actually gives you a piece of paper saying temp license I'd believe it's legit.